# SQL Server 2000 restore error

Tags: sql-server

i'm trying to do point in time restore and following error occurs... and database goes into xxxxx(loading) state...

Backup set cannot be applied because it is on a recovery path inconsistent with database

i have to do RESTORE DATABASE xxxxx WITH RECOVERY to make it proper...
Why its happening?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like you are restoring a database backup file (.BAK) rather than restoring a Transaction Log Backup file (.LOG) i.e. rolling a database foreward, from it's last FULL BACKUP, to a particular point in time.

Was the database, from which the original backup was taken, placed in the FULL Recover model and do you also have Transaction Log backups?

To qualify, a database backup file contains the database data at a specific point in time only. A database can only subsequently be rolled forward to a given point in time using Transaction Log Backups, sourced from the same database as the Full database backup.

Comment: I've appended transaction log to full backup file only.

Comment: Take a look at the following Documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190244%28SQL.90%29.aspx